How to temporary stop Azure API Management Service
I have a configured API Management Service in Azure, which will not be used for specific amount of time. In order to cut costs I would like to just stop it and be able to start it when needed.
I have nowhere found any way to stop it:

I was able to stop other resources like "Web Apps" but not the APIM.
Is there a way to temporary disable APIM or some other technique which will prevent it from consuming costs?

It looks like you can't stop the APIM instance, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1351023/how-to-stop-azure-apim-service.

I see, that is a pity. Is there a way to cut the cost at least?

You can choose the plan by referring to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/api-management/

I have changed the pricing to "basic" yesterday and today I see smaller charge. Unfortunately I cannot change the pricing to "Consumption" , I will need to recreate my resource again.

Yeah If you are facing challenges then you can delete the resource and create a new one for the desire plan


Temporary stopping Azure API Management Service is not possible

As of now, we cannot control starting or stopping of the APIM
directly to the users for any tiers. The operation you can do with APIM is add/update/remove APIs/users/products to it. There are no other management options needed.
If you are using the consumption tier then it will be billed as per the API operation and for other SKU's (Developer, basic etc.) it will be charged per unit bases as documented and if you want to stop the APIM billing for other SKU apart from consumption, then you need to delete your APIM instance.
The way you can provision so that is to do the backup restore and delete the existing APIM and restore it when ever you need it.
To get the restore job done follow the microsoft doc follow the steps befor deleting it.
refer:
Feature-based comparison of the Azure API Management tiers | Microsoft Learn
how to stop azure apim service - Microsoft Q&A answered by MayankBargali-MSFT

I wonder why there is no such possibility? At first glance I do not see any obstacles to stop and start the API. Of course the downline services might not be accessible but thats the choice of the user which stops the APIM. Anyhow since its all we have now I accept the answer:)
